# Exception Removing all Combo Box Items with JComboBox Open

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, removeall

I need to remove all the elements at my JComboBox, using .removeAllItems() it works fine!
But I notice that there is a small problem, maybe a bug? I don't know.

If I leave the JComboBox opened, and then try to remove all the items, an exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
```

I tryed to close the popup before calling the removeAllItems, like this:

```
private void removeAllClassesAvailable() {
        classeComboBox.hidePopup();
        classeComboBox.removeAllItems();
}
```

But still didn't work out !

Maybe because my JComboBox is inside a JTable?

Comment: Can you show the line that is throwing the exception?

Comment: Hopefully someone will be able to answer this soon. If not, consider adding more information and code, best an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like one of the listeners added to the combobox tries to process selection. Try to remove the listener(s) from the combo before removing items and readd after.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a global variable boolean in order to avoid the control keep fireing new events:

```
public static boolean avoidNewEvents;

.............

private void 
    jCBoxSubCategoriaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    // ComboBox 
    //
    if (Form.avoidNewEvents==false) return;
    .............

      //Avoid new events to fire recursively
      FORM.avoidNewEvents=false;

       /  
       jCBoxSubCategoria.removeAllItems();

     //Reset:
     FORM.avoidNewEvents=true;
```